# How to create a shift key + mouse click event that would change the color of a black button to a yellow button on click? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, mouseevent, mouse

I am creating a minesweeper game and am trying to create an event where if the user holds down the shift key and left clicks their mouse simultaneously then the button (background-color is black) that I created for the field will turn yellow to indicate a button that is flagged. Here is what I have so far. The attribute ('data-value', 0) means that that button does not have a mine or number label that will indicate how far it is from the mine.

JS:

```
$('button').getAttribute('data-value', 0).getAttribute('data-x', j).getAttribute('data-y', i).getAttribute('data-visible', false).getAttribute('data-mine', false).click(function (e) {
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        $('button').addClass('flag');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
table td button {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
}

.flag {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What part exactly are you stuck on? The shift-click? The color change? Both?

Comment: that listener at the end of a big `getAttribute` chain looks sketchy, can we simplify that?

Comment: are you not able to detect the key combination for `CTRL+Click` ?

Comment: I think I'm stuck on both. I'm not even sure if the shift-click is working so I'm not sure if the code is right either

Comment: hey, can you mark the answer as correct if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to detect the key combination you can use the following script to do that, see below code try pressing `SHIFT+ mouse left click` to detect it.

```js
let ShiftOn = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    let isShiftOn = e.which == "16";

    (isShiftOn) && (ShiftOn = true);
  }).keyup(function() {
    ShiftOn = false;
  });
  $("#detectable-area").on('click', function() {
    (ShiftOn) && console.log('SHIFT +LEFT Click');
  });
});
```

```css
div#detectable-area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: #c8c8c8;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="detectable-area">Press SHIFT + click anywhere in the div to detect.</div>
```